# How can I migrate this expression code into mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am migrating mule 3 code to mule 4 and this is the code in Expression component .How can I migrate this into mule 4.

```
{
if(vars.deletesVar != null)
{
vars.combinedArray.addAll(vars.deletesVar);
}
if(vars.insertsVar != null)
{
vars.combinedArray.addAll(vars.insertsVar);
}
if (vars.updatesVar != null)
{
vars.combinedArray.addAll(vars.updatesVar);
}
else{
vars.combinedArray=[];
}
}
```

I am new to Mulesoft, and working on migration. Can anyone help me what should I do in this to be work in mule 4 ?

Comment: Please make the title specific to the details of the question. Currently is too generic and there is already a similar titled question.

Comment: Not only similar title, the question is similar too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to use [DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/whats-new-in-dw) which is the expression language for Mule 4, instead of MEL which was the expression language for Mule 3. Read the [migration guide to get tips on how to migrate your expressions](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/migration-mel).

Specifically in DataWeave you should return a single value and assign it to the target variable.

In this case you could replace the `if`s using `default` so you can concatenate the arrays, if any of them is null it is replaced by the default, which I set to an empty array. It is simpler and the intention more clear in my opinion.

Example:

```xml
<set-variable value="#[(vars.deletesVar default []) ++ (vars.insertsVar default []) ++ (vars.updatesVar default [])]" doc:name="combinedArray" variableName="combinedArray"/>
```